# File Upload with Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-jet

I'm using [Oracle JET](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/index.html), and I want to add a file upload capability to my webapp. How can I do that, with Oracle JET?

Comment: Edits for legibility / link to JET.

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman Are you providing any kind of solution or just editing my question?

Comment: Just editing; was in the "Help and Improvements" queue to be edited, so I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The File Picker component was introduced in Oracle JET version 3.2 as:

```
 <oj-file-picker class="oj-filepicker-custom"
              selectOn="click"
              on-select="{{selectListener}}">
```

Check the Oracle JET cookbook for detailed examples on using this.
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=filePicker&demo=basic

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is no file upload component in JET. You can use HTML5 file API to do this.

You can find more information about file API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **oj-file-picker** tag from Oracle JET, to use this tag you need to include the component **ojs/ojfilepicker**.

Reference: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=progressList&demo=basic

Answer (score -1):

There is no JET component/utility for file upload, for this you can implement conventional method of uploading file like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The accept attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 (and earlier versions), and Safari 5 (and earlier).</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Because of security issues, this example will not allow you to upload files.</p>

</body>
</html>
```